# How to check if the line is equal to my specific one?

Tags: python, oop, decorator

I made a function that checks if there is a string in the file and compares it with my 'password', if they match, I raise an exception:

```
@staticmethod       
    def dict_check(password):
        with open('dict.txt', 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                if line == password:
                    return True
            return False
```

after that I put my func in my @property.setter:

```
if not User.dict_check(value):
    raise ValueError("...")
```

When I put password in my instance I always have the same issue:

```
---> 51     raise ValueError("...")
     52 self.__password = value

ValueError: ...
```

Even though my password is different from the string from the .txt file.

Sorry Im like very new in IT, so

Comment: NOTE: the name of my property isn't literally property.setter it's like password.setter

Comment: So why are you checking if the password is **not** present in your if statement when raising the exception? Seems like you want it the other way around, right?

Comment: be careful each `line` ends with the newline separator, do `line.rstrip("\r\n") == password`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `not` operator creates a double negative. So the code you wrote will trigger an exception only if the password does **not** exist in the .txt file. Either remove the not or switch the return values of the method to fix.

Comment: That's right! I removed 'not' and it didn't work. So I also tried line.rstrip("\r\n") == password and it there it is! Thank you .